# Runescape Slayer rewards?

Tags: runescape

When slaying how do you receive the slayer reward points? I have completed 34 slayer tasks under Vanaka and haven't received any points. How can I earn them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get points for finishing slayer tasks, you must first complete the quest [Smoking KIlls](http://www.tip.it/runescape/quests/view/190-smoking-kills). After that, you gain slayer points every time you kill the last monster in a task, starting from the fifth task completed in a row (that is, without discarding a task). You get different amounts of points depending on which slayer master you got the task from (information from [this page](http://www.tip.it/runescape/pages/view/slayer_guide.htm#SmokingKills)):

- Mazchna - 1 points
- Vannaka - 4 points
- Chaeldar - 10 points
- Sumona - 12 points
- Duradel - 15 points
- Kuradal - 18 points

You also get 5X points after your 10th task completed in a row and 15X points after your 50th task completed in a row.

Comment: You only gain points if you complete 5 tasks in a row without doing anything else? I completed the quest and I'm still confused.

Comment: Ah, that's not what I meant. You only gain points if you complete 5 tasks in a row without discarding a task by replacing it with one from a lower level master.

Comment: I have never done that and after now 43 tasks nothing.

Comment: Are you *sure* you don't have points? Have you actually checked the rewards screen at a slayer master? And this is 43 tasks *after* you completed the quest?

Comment: Yes 43 tasks after the quest and I have tried buying items at the slayer master but It says "This requires 15 Slayer Points to buy. You currently have 0".

Comment: I have no explanation for this.

Comment: @murgatroid99 After a recent update this answer is no longer valid.  Just figured it should be updated.  You no longer need to finish Smoking Kills to get slayer points. http://services.runescape.com/m=news/slayer-helmet-and-social-slayer-update

Answer (score 2):

As of 2014, the mechanics for rewarding slayer points has changed a bit and thus the accepted answer is no longer true.

Slayer points can be earned from a few different sources such as *completing Slayer assignments or a special challenge from any Slayer Master bar Turael and Spria, by trading in completed Tuska masks, or completing contracts on the Arc assigned by Ling*

The smoking kills quest is no longer required to start earning points, it now instead doubles the amount of points gained per task. The values are below and assume the player has completed the quest. Players still earn 5x the points for every 10th task and 15x for every 50th task.

- Turael or Spria - 0
- Mazchna or Achtryn - 2
- Vannaka - 4
- Chaeldar - 10
- Sumona - 12
- Duradel or Lapalok - 15
- Kuradal - 18
- Morvran - 20

See the [Runescape Wiki page on Slayer Points](https://runescape.wiki/w/Slayer_points) for more information.

Answer (score -2):

https://runescape.wiki/w/Slayer_reward_point

> Slayer reward points are awarded when a player finishes an assignment or challenge assigned by any Slayer Master (except Turael/Spria). This ability is unlocked after completing the Smoking Kills quest. The higher level the Slayer Master, the more points are received. Slayer reward points can be traded in to any slayer master for various rewards. The approximate value is 943 coins per point (based on 35 points per batch of Slayer Dart runes)

https://runescape.wiki/w/Slayer/Challenges

> Slayer challenges are unique challenges occasionally offered by each respective Slayer Masters to players coming to seek a new assignment. Each master's challenge is different and offers Slayer experience when completed, in addition to the regular slayer experience gained while killing the monsters in the task. For players who have completed Smoking Kills, completing a challenge for most masters also awards Slayer reward points, in addition to any slayer reward points normally gained for completing a slayer assignment. Turael/Spria, and Kuradal, however, do not award slayer reward points for completing their challenges. (When the challenge is finished, the chatbox lists on separate lines the rewards for the challenge itself and the rewards if any for completing an assignment.)
>
> Players may decline the challenge without a slayer point penalty and accept a regular task instead. Declining will not permanently ban the opportunity to receive a challenge task; players may be assigned it again in the future.
>
> **Note:** Slayer challenges do count as assignments, take this into account when you're nearly on your 10th and/or 50th task (for more points).
>   Turael/Spria
>   Turael or Spria asks the player to visit his or her new basement to slay all monsters there in one visit.
>
> The monsters are:
>
> - Level 5 goblin (2)
> - Level 11 goblin (2)
> - Level 13 goblin (1)
> - Level 11 wolf (2)
> - Level 14 wolf (3)
> - Level 12 minotaur (5)
>
> None of these monsters require any specialized equipment to defeat.
>
> When done, the player is rewarded 1,000 Slayer experience for the challenge itself, in addition to any Slayer experience earned during the task.

Comment: This answer (or at least the first paragraph) seem to be entirely plagiarized from http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Slayer_reward_point. Please at least summarize the *relevant* parts of the source and cite it.